# Problem of updating data in a React context with TypeScript class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, react-context

I'm working on a React context with TypeScript class components, and I'm trying to update a string when the user clicks on a button. Unfortunately, even though I'm not getting any error messages in the console, the "data" data is not updating when I click the button. I would like to know if anyone can help me solve this problem.

this is my context './context'

```
import React from 'react';

type MyContextType = {
  data: string;
  setData: (value: string) => void;
};

export interface MDTContextProps {
  children: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const MyContext = React.createContext<MyContextType>({
  data: 'test',
  setData: () => ({}),
});

class MyContextProvider extends React.Component<MDTContextProps, MyContextType> {
  props: MDTContextProps;

  constructor(props: MDTContextProps) {
    super(props);

    this.props = props;  

    this.state = {
      data: '',
      setData: this.updateData,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
      console.log('mounter')
  }

  updateData = (value: string) => {
    this.setState({
      data: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
      {this.props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>;
  }
}

export { MyContextProvider, MyContext };
```

this my app

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './context/MDTContext';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <div>
          {context.data}
          <button onClick={() => context.setData('New Data!')}>Update Data</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show us where `<MyContextProvider>` and `<App>` are relative to eachother in the component tree?

Comment: why are you using setData in this.state.

Comment: @NicholasTower Here is the tree structure for the <MyContextProvider> and <App>
/src
 /context
  /MDTContext.tsx
 App.tsx

Comment: `why are you using setData in this.state.` They're doing it so they don't recreate the context object on every render. Doing this via state is not unusual in a class component. In a function component you'd be more likely to do it via `useMemo`

Comment: `src /context /MDTContext.tsx App.tsx ` I'm not asking where the files are on your computer, i'm asking you to show me the code that renders a `<MyContextProvider>` element and an `<App>` element. For example, maybe there's a component that does `render () { return <MyContextProvider><App /></MyContextProvider>; }`. Without seeing that, i can't tell if the provider is being rendered correctly.

Answer (score -2):

you need to rerender the child you can use useEffect